# Standalone desktop wallpaper module to display wallpaper without explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, window-manager

I am modding the windows 11 user interface but since it is not officially out yet and the backend shouldn't have too much difference, let's just assume we are working with windows 10:

So I am using a custom app launcher interface [MyDockFinder](http://www.mydockfinder.com) and wants to terminate explorer.exe but still wants the desktop wallpaper to be properly shown instead of either black or white color. So I am wondering if there is any way to stop the wallpaper to change to black white, or is there any standalone add-ons or plugins (I am thinking about [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) but I am not sure where to find a skin to fit the case) that can do the job of displaying the image of the wallpaper at the most bottom layer of all windows or some hacks that I probably wouldn't understand but will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: We cannot assume you are running Windows 11, the differences between Windows 10 and Windows 11, are too great to do that. Sounds like MyDockFinder and Rainmeter will have to be updated to support Windows 11.  If you cannot live without those applications you should immediately downgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Terminating Explorer means there's no canvas to display anything. The wallpaper doesn't *change*, it's *destroyed*. You will need to write your own application for displaying anything.